# Firefox: How to reload form *without* caching user-input?

Tags: html, forms, firefox, webforms

**BACKGROUND:**

When you have a page that includes an HTML form, and you refresh/reload the page or use the back button, Firefox is kind enough to repopulate your inputs with what was entered before you navigated away.

**PROBLEM:**

For some use-cases, this is *not* the desired functionality. Fortunately, there are ways around this behavior if you are willing to use one of the "redraw without caching" options below:

```
redraw without caching  ;; Press CTRL+F5 
redraw without caching  ;; Press form "Reset" button while holding SHIFT
redraw without caching  ;; Cut the address from the address bar, Paste it back into the address bar, press ENTER
redraw with caching     ;; Press F5
```

The problem is, not all users know these options, and some just want a simple "Reset" button that they can click on with the mouse without having to use the keyboard.

**QUESTION:**

Is there a way to get Firefox to do a "redraw without caching" in a way that lets the user simply click on a button with the mouse, and *not* have to use the keyboard?

Comment: so what you want is a Reset Button on your WebPage.. is it so ?

Comment: the standard reset button, when used, apparently requires the user to press the shift key to get a "redraw without caching" I'm looking for a method that does not require the user to use the keyboard at all

Comment: Added two new methods, one that just seems confusing, and one that uses an add-on (which I haven't tried, but has the functionality you are looking for)

Comment: After thinking about this a bit more, I'm not quite sure if you want to just redraw the from, or the whole page. If you want to reset the form, you can just use Javascript to clear all the inputs.

Comment: The problem with clearing all the inputs: suppose some of the inputs have a default value that you do not want to have wiped out, but instead restored to the pristine state before the user started changing stuff on the form.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the sake of completeness:

```
<script>
document.FORMNAME.reset()
</script>
```

It resets the form with the name `FORMNAME` on every reload of the page.

Answer (score 2):

Method 1:
Holding Shift + clicking the Refresh button will do a refresh without cache. This isn't a mouse only, but this is the closest I can think of while using the mouse.

Method 2:
If you really want to use no mouse, on a Mac, you can drag and hold the favicon off the URL bar, then drag and drop it back into the URL bar. Can't confirm on Windows, and this just seems more confusing than holding Shift.

Method 3: Install [Hard Refresh](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/hard-refresh/) add-on, which installs ability in context menu.

Answer (score 2):

How about a link to the same URL that the user is currently on?

Since the browser treats it as a navigation, rather than a refresh/reload, the form data won't be remembered.

Note that "reset" is a different term used specifically for reverting forms to their original state *without* reloading the page, as in `<input type="reset">`, don't confuse it with refresh/reload which are terms for getting a page to be requested again from the server